how to use custom labels in prometheus alerts
I am using aws managed prometheus and I have configured this to scrape metrics for EKS cluster setup in AWS.
When I run the api call to the below URL I see a lot of labels. I want to use these labels as part of the alerts that is sent to slack channel
GET /api/v1/labels

For example above API query has the label label_cluster_name, I want to use this in the alert for different EKS clusters. I do not want to hard code the cluster name in each alert. It should automatically pick the cluster name and mention it in the alert description or alert title . How do I do this ?

This question is similar to: How to get a pod's labels in Prometheus when pulling the metrics from Kube State Metrics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

/api/v1/labels returns a list of label names, and without query parameter match[] those labels names are from all metrics. Most likely label_cluster_name is a label of kube_pod_labels or something like that.
